# How to stop an animation that is queued using jquery.timing plugin

Tags: jquery, animation, deque

How do you stop an animation that is queued using [this](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/usage/) plugin

This is how I queue the `fadeOut()`:

`$('#myDiv').wait(2000).fadeOut("slow");`

This doesn't work:

`$('#myDiv').stop(true, true).clearQueue().show();`

Comment: Have you tried delay() insteadof wait() not sure if it'll work

Comment: Tea that worked. Can't believe I didn't try that! Can you answer the question instead of a comment so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, jQuery has deprecated `.wait()` in favor of the `.delay()` function. There is no existing documentation for `.wait()` on the jQuery API site. As shown in the jQuery documentation, there is no built-in way to cancel a `.delay()` function once it's been called. A better alternative would be to simply use vanilla Javascript's built-in timer function ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)) `setTimeout()`, and its canceling partner `clearTimeout()`.

**EDIT:** Using the plugin's `.wait()` function, you could cancel the set timer using `$.unwait()`.

Comment: Don't think you read my question. It's from a plugin. Got it working now, thanks!

Comment: Oops! Also didn't see @Jackson 's comment. Just gonna pop in another answer for others who might stumble upon this. Care to share your solution?

Comment: Solution was Jackson's answer, replacing wait() with delay().